# Create SortedMap from Iterator in scala

Tags: scala, collections, sortedmap

I have an `val it:Iterator[(A,B)]` and I want to create a `SortedMap[A,B]` with the elements I get out of the `Iterator`. The way I do it now is:

```
val map = SortedMap[A,B]() ++ it
```

It works fine but feels a little bit awkward to use. I checked the `SortedMap` doc but couldn't find anything more elegant. Is there something like:

```
 it.toSortedMap
```

or

```
SortedMap.from(it)
```

in the standard Scala library that maybe I've missed?

**Edit**: mixing both ideas from @Rex's answer I came up with this:

```
SortedMap(it.to:_*)
```

Which works just fine and  avoids having to specify the type signature of `SortedMap`. Still looks funny though, so further answers are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feature you are looking for does exist for other combinations, but not the one you want.  If your collection requires just a single parameter, you can use `.to[NewColl]`.  So, for example,

```
import collection.immutable._

Iterator(1,2,3).to[SortedSet]
```

Also, the `SortedMap` companion object has a varargs apply that can be used to create sorted maps like so:

```
SortedMap( List((1,"salmon"), (2,"herring")): _* )
```

(note the `: _*` which means use the contents as the arguments).  Unfortunately this requires a `Seq`, not an `Iterator`.

So your best bet is the way you're doing it already.

Comment: Very good points both, mixing them I came up with an idea, which i added to the question.

Comment: @Chirlo - Good idea!  Note that it's not as efficient as the `++` solution because it does need to create an intermediate `Seq`.  But if you aren't in a situation where efficiency matters much (which is most situations) then it could be a good alternative!

Comment: Note `SortedMap.from` is part of the [API of Scala 2.13](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/SortedMap$.html#from[K,V](it:scala.collection.IterableOnce[(K,V)])(implicitevidence$46:Ordering[K]):CC[K,V]).