# Using Scala 2.10 `to` to convert a List to a SortedMap

Tags: scala, collections, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a `scala.collection.immutable.List` of pairs to a `scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap` using the new `to` method from Scala 2.10, but I get a compile-time error:

```
scala> List((1, "Fred"), (2, "Barney")).to[scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap]
<console>:10: error: scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap takes two type parameters, expected: one
              List((1, "Fred"), (2, "Barney")).to[SortedMap]
                                                  ^
```

Can this be done using the `to` method? Am I missing an intermediate method call?

Comment: as for the why this doesn't work, this is because `.to` is restricted to target collection that have a single type parameter (and an available `CanBuildFrom` implicit): `.to[Col[_]] : Col[A]`. This also means that you cannot convert to a collection type that has no type parameter at all, like `BitSet` for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@gourlaysama already explained why it does not compile, and @Chirlo provided the simplest (and recommended) work around: `SortedMap( list: _*)`.

I'd like to propose an alternative:

```
import collection.Traversable
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
implicit class RichPairTraversable[A,B]( t: Traversable[(A,B)] ) {
  def toPairCol[Col[A,B]](implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, (A,B), Col[A, B]]): Col[A, B] = {
    val b = cbf()
    b.sizeHint(t)
    b ++= t
    b.result
  }  
}
```

Some test in the REPL:

```
scala> List((1, "Fred"), (2, "Barney")).toPairCol[scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap]
res0: scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap[Int,String] = Map(1 -> Fred, 2 -> Barney)

scala> List((1, "Fred"), (2, "Barney")).toPairCol[scala.collection.immutable.HashMap]
res1: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,String] = Map(1 -> Fred, 2 -> Barney)
```

Now, I will probably not use it in production, given that doing `SortedMap( list: _* )` is not that
hard and requires no magic.

Answer (score 9):

I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042421/create-sortedmap-from-iterator-in-scala) some time ago and came up with this:

```
SortedMap( list: _*)
```

So you can do it like :

```
val map =  SortedMap( List((1, "Fred"), (2, "Barney")): _*)
```

The `_*` means you take the `Seq`s elements instead of the `Seq` itself as parameter.

Comment: That's actually what I did to fix my code. I wanted to use the new `to` method, though :-).

Comment: actually the `.to` is not needed in here, you can directly give the list (with `:_*`) to `SortedMap()`.

Comment: Right! My original problem was making a `SortedMap` out of an `Iterator`, in that case I did need the `to`

Comment: Note that SortedMap takes an implicit ordering on the keys.  If your list isn't sorted by key, but you want to maintain the list's order, you can use ListMap instead.